# Comparison of GTK+, Qt and MATLAB for developing a GUI for a scientific program written in C++

Tags: c++, matlab, qt, user-interface, gtk

I've written a rather large scale program in C++, and now someone wanted me to make a GUI for it (in Windows). The program generates data that should be plotted. I know that I can use either gtk+, Qt or MATLAB(using MEX files) to build the GUI.

Since my program is a scientific program with its output some data that should be post-processed and plotted, how are the above approaches compared to each other? Up to now I've used MATLAB because I think it has more built-in tools available for scientific plotting and data manipulating. Since having a GUI for the program is not much important to me, ease of use is probably the most important factor.

Comment: If you just want to show plots, you might want to check out [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) as well.

Comment: It pretty much depends on what "GUI" features you want. MATLAB is fine for simple GUIs, but if you want to customize things on a finer level you're going into a dead end at some point.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend to use Qt because:

- It's cross-platform and and covers wide range of operating systems (including mobile)
- Writing in C++ gives you the opportunity to use libraries
  like the STL, Boost, etc;
- Using C++ gives you the benefit of running your app at high speed
- It is opensource and has a fast speed in getting better
- It has the a nice GUI designer and a very capable IDE (Qt Creator)
- The API design is excellent and easy to use
- It has a great documentation which is easy to read
- It has the Qt translation system which enables you to have a multilingual app
- The GUI layout system where the widgets resize themselves according to a layout makes everything much easier
- The QML gives you the power to create fantastic GUI with great graphics and animations
- It has great support for networking and connectivity(socket, SSL, www, IPC, ...)
- It has QTestLib for testing the code
- It has many language binding if you don't want to use C++

Also there are some mature plotting libraries developed for Qt like [QCustomPlot](http://www.qcustomplot.com/) and [QWT](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/).

QCustomPlot is a Qt C++ library for plotting which focuses on making good looking and high quality 2D plots, graphs and charts, as well as offering high performance for realtime visualization applications.

QWt provides a framework for 2D plots. It is so mature and good at performance.

Comment: I use CodeBlocks MinGW for compiling and developing my code, which is (as far as I know) 32 bit, although my Windows is x64. In the Qt download list, it doesn't list Qt for Win 64 bit and MinGW. What can I do?

Comment: I think you should build it yourself. see https://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/22257

Comment: Most 64-bit Windows environments can run 32-bit applications, so feel free to use 32-bit Qt libraries. The one exception I've come across is WinRE.